# jquery select on form has to be reselected to work after each page load

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery in order to disable text boxes on my page.  The issue I am running into is that by default because its stored in the database it loads the page with "remote_server" set to 0. Even with this being set automatically the fields are still able to be modified.  I must click on the selection drop down and reselect "no" for it to work.

Here is my JS

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("remote_server")[0]
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if ( strUser == 0 ) {

$('select[name=remote_server]').change(function(){
var inputs = $('input[name^=ftp_],select[name^=ftp_]');
$(this).val() == "0" ? inputs.attr("disabled", "disabled") : inputs.removeAttr("disabled");
});
}
```

My remote_server HTML code for the drop down selection.

```
<select name="remote_server" class="required">
<option></option>
<option value="1" <?php if($remote=="1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Yes</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($remote=="0") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

Loading the page I an see where the option 0 is selected aswell which is why this puzzles me

```
<select name="remote_server" class="required">
<option></option>
<option value="1" >Yes</option>
<option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Do you mean change event is not triggered at first?

Comment: When I load the page I can modify the fields that I shouldnt, if I click on the remote_server option dropdown and simply click on no again, then it correctly doesnt allow me to modify the fields.  Its like the jquery somehow doesnt see that its been selected already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trigger the `change` event:

```
$('select[name=remote_server]').change(function(){
   var inputs = $('input[name^=ftp_],select[name^=ftp_]');
   $(this).val() == "0" 
   ? inputs.attr("disabled", "disabled") 
   : inputs.removeAttr("disabled");
}).change() // trigger the event
```

Note that as of jQuery 1.6 for setting/getting properties of the elements, `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`:

```
var $inputs = $('input[name^=ftp_],select[name^=ftp_]');

$('select[name=remote_server]').change(function(){
     $inputs.prop('disabled', this.value === 0)
}).change();
```

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly.  Now just one last thing is that when the options are enabled again the drop down within fields im disabling stays disabled.  All the text boxes come back up for me to edit when I change remote_server to yes with the exception of "ftp_mode" which is a drop down with the options active or passive

Comment: @user1913843 Are you sure that element has a name attribute which starts with `ftp_`?

Comment: yes

<select name="ftp_mode" class="required">
<option></option>
<option value="1" <?php if($ftpmode=="1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Active</option>
<option value="0" <?php if($ftpmode=="0") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Passive</option>
</select>